# How to create MS Teams Survey App Messaging Extension

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am currently creating a survey app for ms teams similar to Polly.ai/survey monkey
The flow would be
User installs app,
app appears as messaging extension on the chat window,
user clicks app to opens page to create survey,
on submit an adaptive card is generated,
the same is responded back to teams,
The new card appears on the message Hi,
I am currently creating a survey app for ms teams similar to Polly.ai/survey monkey
The flow would be
User installs app,
app appears as messaging extension on the chat window,
user clicks app to opens page to create survey,
on submit an adaptive card is generated=>
the same is responded back to teams =>
The new card appears on the message create pane,
User hits enter to post the survey to the group,
All the group members respond to the survey ,
The same is logged

Can anyone help me in providing some links from where I can start.
Or maybe throw some light on what should be my approach.

My progress so far.
Created a teams bot,
On messaging extension invoke returned url that contains HTML for survey creation which is created in vue.js. Used msteams js to submit the json for created survey back to the bot,
Generated an adaptive card with json received and the a new survey created in db,
Sent the card back to teams as message attachment,
The card is displayed in message create pane,
User hits enter to post the card in the group,
Caught the action.submit event from adaptive card on bot framework.

Also, please note while I am generating the card I don’t have user email in the turncontext as well.

Please throw some light on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [App templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/app-templates) available. I think for your case [Poll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/app-templates#poll) and [Survey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/app-templates#survey) are the best app template available.

Thanks